# Adjoint action of a Lie algebra in MAGMA

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

Let's say I have a Lie algebra $L$ and an element $x$ in $L$.  I need to compute $(\mathrm{ad} \ x)^n(y)$ for several values of $y$ and a particular value of $n$.  I thought the best way to do this would be to compute the matrix that represents $M = (\mathrm{ad} \ x)^n$ so that I could just multiply this with whatever.

I can get the matrix of the adjoint action using `AdjointMatrix(L, x)`.  This gives me an element of type `AlgMatLieElt` which makes sense.  I can't raise that to the $n$th power, I need to coerce it into a MatrixAlgebra, then enxponentiate it, then coerce it back into a Matrix Lie algebra element form.  Fine, call this guy $M$.

But how on earth do I multiply elements of $L$ by $M$?  Whether $M$ is in matrix algebra form or Lie algebra form the command `M * y` gives an error.  I have searched the magma handbook but I find that it doesn't do a very good job of collecting information in the location you would expect to find it in.  So does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why not write a magma function that takes $x,y,n$ as arguments and returns $\operatorname{ad}(x)^n(y)$? It's probably simpler than doing all these conversions. f:=function(x,y,n) output:=y; for i in [1..n] do output := x*output; end for; return output; end function; will do it.